# authentication fails always

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();

var User = require('../models/authentication');
var todo_controller = require('../controllers/todoController');
var auth_controller = require('../controllers/authController');

var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;


passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
 function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ clientId: username }, function (err, user) {
     if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
     if (!user) {
    return done(null, false);
      }
      if (user.clientSecret != password) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, user);
     });
  }
));

router.post('/api/me',
  passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
  });



module.exports = router;
```

I am using express js , mongoose, and passports.
this is the router.js file. The authentication not works, it returns "unauthorized" always. is this the correct way to use passport..i didn't find an easy reference to use passport.

Comment: how should I pass username and password to authenticate? currently giving it as form parameters

Comment: the problem was resolved by using _passport-local_ instead of _passport-http_

Comment: I have referred this example (https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example)